# ios application generation ipa from termminal

Tags: ios, build, terminal, ipa

I am trying to build IPA from terminal. I tried the following steps:
Step 1:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target "appname" -sdk "iphoneos" -configuration Release
```

Step 2:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "appname" -o "/Users/Pictures/" -sign "iPhone Developer:xxxxx" --embed /Users//Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/xxxxxx.mobileprovision"
```

I didn't get any error but I am not getting any response. I have been waiting for more than 30 minutes. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I have given a brief description of steps to follow, and parameters to pass while generating an ipa using terrminal below:

1) Go to the folder which contains the MyApp.xcodeproject file in terminal

2) By using the command given below you will get all the Targets of the application

/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list 

3) After the above command is executed, you will get a list of targets of which you should select a specific target you need to generate .ipa

/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target $TARGET -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release

4) The above command builds the project and creates a .app file.The path to locate the .app file is"./build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app"

5) After Build gets succeeded then execute the following command to generate .ipa of the application using Developer Name and Provisioning Profile using the syntax below:

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v “${TARGET}.app” -o “${OUTDIR}/${TARGET}.ipa” –sign “${IDENTITY}” –embed “${PROVISONING_PROFILE}”

Explanation of each Parameter in the above syntax:

${TARGET}.app == Target path (ex :/Users/XXXXXX/desktop/Application/build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app) ${OUTDIR} == Select the output directory(Where you want to save .ipa file) ${IDENTITY} == iPhone Developer: XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXX)(which can be obtained from Keychain access) ${PROVISONING_PROFILE} == Path to the provisioning profile(/Users/XXXXXX/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.mobileprovision”) 


6)ipa will be generated at selected output directory "${OUTDIR}"
```

Comment: i am getting following error Done checking the original app
### Embedding 
error: Unable to copy '/Users/firestreamworldwide/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/4791f875-2b51-4123-b751-d7ef733594ec.mobileprovision' to '/var/folders/jp/fz9g88dx1jb_4d1d35lg09040000gp/T/3_H8_Tgf5n/Payload/DeliveryStream.app/embedded.mobileprovision'